# Arraylist of classes

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Ok i need some help with a little syntax problem. I have a class and i want it to put it into an arraylist, and populate the arraylist using a for loop.
Here is an example of what i want:

```
    public class w{
    int x;
    int y;
    }
    Arraylist m = new Arraylist();
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
  {
          m[i].add(w.x);
          m[i].add(w.y);

  }
```

Yes the code isn't functioning its just an example of what i want it to do. I don't know the syntax and I want an arraylist with classes that can be retrieved by giving the i and get the both variables only by that 'i';
Any help will be apreciated. Thank you very much for your time, sorry for the lousy description but i can't be more specific.

Comment: What do you want to put in your ArrayList?  Multiple instances of the class named `w` or the values of w.x and w.y?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Arraylist of Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694999/dynamic-arraylist-of-classes)

Comment: It appears that you're confused about how classes and ArrayLists work.  When you say `m[i]` it implies that you want an array of ArrayLists.  Is that true?  When you say you want to add `w.x` and `w.y` to a list, that implies that you want x and y to be static variables.  It seems more likely that you want to create an ArrayList that contains multiple instances of _class w_ but that's not what your code suggests.  Please try to describe exactly what you want more clearly.

Comment: its already solved but yes you are right. Arraylist that contains multiple instances of class w. Yes i will start learning the basic concepts to stop confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps this will be enough of a guide as to how to use `ArrayList` properly. I changed your class name from `w` to `W` to match the usual Java coding conventions.

```
public class W {
    int x;
    int y;
    public W(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

ArrayList<W> m = new ArrayList<W>(); // can be 'new ArrayList<>()` in Java 7
m.add(new W(1, 2));
m.add(new W(5,-3));
// etc.

for (int i=0; i<m.size(); i++) {
    W w = m.get(i);
    System.out.println("m[" + i + "]=(" + w.x + "," + w.y + ")");
}

for (W w : m) {
    System.out.println("next W: (" + w.x + "," + w.y + ")");
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good guess as to what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @jahroy - Definitely a [SWAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Wild-Ass_Guess) :)

Comment: yes thank you this is what i have been looking for. Sorry about the mess :).

Comment: @TedHopp what if you do not want to enter values by passing them through arguments and you want to specifically assign each field, how would you do it then?

Comment: @solleks - Do you mean construct a `W` and set the field values in separate statements? To do that is not hard: you would need to provide a default (no-arg) constructor and then either making the fields `public` (so they can be assigned directly) or provide setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the square bracket notation to access collections by index in Java.  If and how you can depends on the particular collection API.  In the case of `List`, there is a second version of the add method that takes an index as argument.

```
List<Integer> m = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
  {
          m.add(i, w.x);
          m.add(i, w.y);

  }
```

Comment: so that means i can just do m[i].w.x and retrieve the value of x?

Comment: you can retrievewith m.get(i);

Comment: and if i want only the value of x? since get(i) gets the both of them?

Comment: You can't recover x anymore, you overwrote it.  If you want to keep both, perhaps storing the actual 'w's in the list would be more useful!

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` isn't an array in the traditional sense; it is an **object**.  You will have to respect how one can access the elements of type `List`, which [can be found with the Java 7 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Namely you have the following two options available to you to place values into it.

`.add(E element)` which takes as a parameter an object that's of the same generic type, and

`.addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection)`, which takes as a parameter another collection type.  You can use this in conjunction with [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29), if you're trying to place a primitive array into your `List`.

Some final things:

- It's more desirable to code to the interface rather than the concrete type.  This way, you don't care if you need to start using a `LinkedList` instead of an `ArrayList`.
- You should type your list or Java will *warn* you of unchecked operations.  These can be unsafe if you get carried away with what you place into your `List`.
- Furthermore, you won't be able to retrieve the specific fields/functions from the `List` without using `instanceof`, since everything stored in there would be an `Object`, which isn't desirable.

Comment: Your comments are all accurate and on point, but I think they will be lost on the OP, who appears confused about several basic Java concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way..

```
public class w{
    int x;
    int y;
    }
  w ref1=new w();
  w ref2=new w();
    Arraylist<w> m = new Arraylist<w>();  
    m.add(ref1);
    m.add(ref2);
```

or you can do

```
for(some condition)
{
    m.add(new w());
}
```